# how to make secure SWFs?

Tags: flash

please tell me how to make secure SWF files, so that decompilers like sothink won't be able to decompile these swf files at all.

i have been assigned some research work to find out the stuff to make swf files highly secured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't any way to prevent SWF files from being decompiled. You can obfuscate the code, although that still won't prevent it from being decompiled. If you are trying to prevent piracy, the best option is to perform some piece of the logic/computation on your server and have your SWF make use of this service so that the SWF file is dependent on server-side logic that others cannot download.

Comment: thanx dear for this, yes u may be right.

see what i did, is used one of swf file and then decompiled it with sothink decompiler,and now  the sothink is supporting conversion to flex aplications as well, 

i also downloaded one encrytion softawre from amataya named secureSWF, which is good, and encryted my swf with this and now this encryted swf is not getting decompiled by sothink. 

see the basic prob with swf is that, it is open file format, so n e one can read it easily, 

n e ways thanx for this gud stuff, i appreciate, have a gr8 time